# gdal complains about wrong crs

Tags: gdal

I am trying to generate a KMZ from GeoTIFF and visualization under Google Earth brings me to the middle of the pacific ocean and no image is shown. The conversion command complains:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\superpuesto>gdal_translate.exe -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY result.tif out.kmz -co FORMAT=JPEG
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

Input file size is 16087, 43882
Warning 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
Warning 1: The definition of projected CRS EPSG:25830 got from GeoTIFF keys is not the same as the one from the EPSG registry, which may cause issues during reprojection operations. Set GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE configuration option to EPSG to use official parameters (overriding the ones from GeoTIFF keys), or to GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code.
```

geotiff info:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\superpuesto>gdalinfo result.tif
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: result.tif
Size is 16087, 43882
Warning 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
Warning 1: The definition of projected CRS EPSG:25830 got from GeoTIFF keys is not the same as the one from the EPSG registry, which may cause issues during reprojection operations. Set GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE configuration option to EPSG to use official parameters (overriding the ones from GeoTIFF keys), or to GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code.
Coordinate System is:
ENGCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N",
    EDATUM[""],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (547285.079942769254558,4091587.083549421280622)
Pixel Size = (0.020000000000000,-0.020000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  547285.080, 4091587.084)
Lower Left  (  547285.080, 4090709.444)
Upper Right (  547606.820, 4091587.084)
Lower Right (  547606.820, 4090709.444)
Center      (  547445.950, 4091148.264)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  NoData Value=0
```

What parameters can I pass to the command to solve this issue?

Comment: There is a more critical problem `Warning 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db`. Without the proj.db database GDAL cannot reproject data. There is something wrong with your GDAL installation. Perhaps the PROJ_LIB environmental variable is not set right.

Comment: OMG, didn't notice that error. I am totally new to GDAL. I will check out my installation again. It makes sense, as no matter what I chose as projection it returned an unknow reference system! Thanks!